# Is it possible to use UTC Offset instead of timezone name on iCal.net?

Tags: c#, dday, ical-dotnet

My application stores the UTC offset on users profile (-03:00, for instance) and as this page from iCal.net Wiki mentions it seems that I can only use the timezone to assign to the event: https://github.com/rianjs/ical.net/wiki/Working-with-time-zones.

Do I have any other option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ical.net uses NodaTime under the hood to do time zone conversions, which means you can use the `Etc/GMT` family of zones. Wikipedia has [a nice list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). In your case, you would specify a time zone of `Etc/GMT-3`:

```
const string ianaZone = "Etc/GMT-3";
var start = DateTime.Now;
var end = start.AddHours(1);

var vEvent = new Event
{
    DtStart = new CalDateTime(start, ianaZone),
    DtEnd = new CalDateTime(end, ianaZone),
};
```